# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near '/'

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm using this query

```
Insert Into Menus(null, 'Item One', 'Desc') // First Parent Item
Insert Into Menus(null, 'Item Two', 'Desc') // Second Parent Item
Insert Into Menus(null, 'Item Three', 'Desc') // Third Parent Item

Insert Into Menus(1, 'Item Sub One', 'Desc') // Child of First Parent Item
Insert Into Menus(2, 'Item Sub Two', 'Desc') // Child of Second Parent Item
Insert Into Menus(3, 'Item Sub Three', 'Desc') // Child of Third Parent Item
```

and I get this error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '/'

Comment: SQL comments start with `--`, not `//`

Comment: yes menus is a table

Comment: This is the link of the dynamic menu i'm doing

http://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2015/02/create-dynamic-menu-in-aspnet-mvc.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the first set of parentheses Fix the 3 column names to their correct names:

```
Insert Into Menus (col1name, col2,col3) values (null, 'Item One', 'Desc');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another problem :

```
// this is NOT a correct SQL comment
/* this is a correct SQL comment */ 
-- this also is a correct SQL comment
```